# SQL Server : execute stored procedure from another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures.

1. `Proc1` executes a SQL statement and results a data table as a result set.
2. I need to use the datatable in a select SQL that resides in `proc2` as a datasource. like,

   ```
   SELECT Col1 
   FROM (Exec Proc1)
   ```

How can I do it? This syntax here shows error in SQL Server.

Comment: If it only returns data without modifying it, maybe that stored procedure should be a function.

Answer (score 1):

you could store your result in a Table Variable

```
DECLARE @TableVar TABLE (col1 varchar,col2 int,...)
insert into @TableVar
exec (Proc1)

select Col1 from @TableVar
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that table variables lack statistics and thus might throw the query optimizer to very wrong a path.

Comment: Stijn Thanks for the idea,
Is there any other possibilities without using #temp table or table variable?

Comment: You cannot use the results of a stored proc directly - you need to store that into an in-memory or temporary table, this a duplicate of your question :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847327/select-a-column-returned-by-a-stored-procedure